# SQL Condition with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this task:
Write a single query to display the fname and lname of employees whose salary is higher than $5000.
The problem is that there is 2 tables and fname and lname is from the table "employee" and salary is from the table "Job". How do I make this condition work?

I can only write this query, but I don't know how to write the fact that salary is in another table.

```
SELECT fname, lname FROM employee WHERE fixed_salary > 5000;
```

Please, help and thank you!  :)

Comment: how are your tables connected/joined?

Comment: You need to join the two tables. Since you didn't show us your tables' schema, there is no way we can tell you how to do that.

Comment: there is foreign key job_id

Comment: *I have this task* indeed

Comment: Is job_id a key in employee?  That would be an odd relational design.  I would expect more likely that there would be a foreign key in job like employee_id that relates the employee who has the job, with the job.  Please clarify your structure.  In any case you need to join the 2 tables together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT fname, lname FROM employee 
INNER JOIN Job ON employee.job_id=job.job_id 
WHERE fixed_salary > 5000;
```

Comment: this worked. Thank you so much! I'll mark it as a correct answer after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

basic SQL joining, read something about e.g. here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

```
SELECT
e.fname,
e.lname,
j.fixed_salary
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN Job j ON j.id = e.job_id
WHERE j.fixed_salary > 5000;
```